# joining tables with merge command in R

Tags: r, join, merge

I have two tables that I'd like to join using the column "SPENO", but am receiving this error:

```
Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column
```

Here are the commands I'm using:

```
setwd("P:/Users/Richmond/PEP_tagData")

read.csv("pepdeployments.csv", header=TRUE)
read.csv("pepdeployments_endDate.csv", header=TRUE)

pep_deploy1 <- "pepdeployments.csv"
pep_deploy2 <- "pepdeployments_endDate.csv"

combined <- merge(x=pep_deploy1,y=pep_deploy2,by.x="SPENO",by.y="SPENO")
```

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: You should add a tag indicating what language you are using. This will allow the question to be picked up by the right people.

Comment: I am using the R language. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: `merge()` throws that particular error message when you specify a column name that does not exist in the input data.frame to which it applies. Hence, the column name `SPENO` probably does not exist in one or both of your two data.frames.

Comment: What do you get when you submit this command: `names(pep_deploy1); names(pep_deploy2)`?

Comment: The column name SPENO is in both data frames.

Comment: @ Jean V. Adams - I get NULL when submitting the command.

Comment: what does `str(pep_deploy1)` and `str(pep_deploy2)` give? Are the SPENO columns present?

Comment: str(pep_deploy1) returns chr "pepdeployments.csv". Is the problem that my data frame is of the object class character? Perhaps joins don't work on chr data types?

Comment: You haven't read in your data correctly. Edit your question with the command you're using to read in your data. More than likely you mean `pep_deploy1 <- read.csv("pepdeployments.csv")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not reading your data in correctly. You need to assign the `read.csv(...)` to an object

```
setwd("P:/Users/Richmond/PEP_tagData")

pep_deploy1 <- read.csv("pepdeployments.csv", header=TRUE)
pep_deploy2 <- read.csv("pepdeployments_endDate.csv", header=TRUE)

combined <- merge(x=pep_deploy1,y=pep_deploy2,by.x="SPENO",by.y="SPENO")
```

---

What you're doing is:

Reading in the .csv file, but just printing it to the console. It's not being assigned to any objects:

```
read.csv("pepdeployments.csv", header=TRUE)
read.csv("pepdeployments_endDate.csv", header=TRUE)
```

Then assigning the strings `pepdeployments.csv` and `pepdeployments_endDate.csv` to the objects. So your objects are just those strings, not the data.

```
pep_deploy1 <- "pepdeployments.csv"
pep_deploy2 <- "pepdeployments_endDate.csv"
```

Comment: after taking a closer look, it appears that the new data table has NA values for all fields that were joined/merged from the y=pep_deploy2.

Comment: @biscuit - that depends on what type of join you want. Do you want an inner/left/right/outer? Take a look at the `all` argument of `?merge`.

Comment: turns out the merge worked successfully after all and the NA columns were just an artifact of the csv.